# WPF image.source change during runtime, from byte[]. But image is blank(white)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am trying to change an image for `image1` during runtime. However the image turns blank(blank), what am I doing wrong?

`ImageAsBytes` is a `Byte[]` containing an image.
`ScrollViewer1` is the where `image1` is located.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImagesAsBytes, 0, ImagesAsBytes.Length))
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = ms;
                image.EndInit();

            }
image1.Source = image; 
scrollViewer1.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Image can't be displayed because the MemoryStream you are using is being disposed. Remove the surrounding `using` block and see if that helps. (you would need to dispose of the stream manually if you don't need it anymore then)

Comment: seems to work only problem i now got is that the size of the image (bitmapimage) is different then the original, the size is a lot smaller.

Comment: That's another problem. Have you tried setting the Stretch property on your image control?

Comment: its not the stretch property, i think the problem occurs with the reading from the stream.

Comment: Oke found what the problem was, had to set image.pixelheight and width manualy